# python loops keep crashing

Tags: python, loops

Here is my code

```
def time_to_end_of_world(p_spread,p_cure):
    ...:     my_world=set_up_cities()
    ...:     zombify(my_world,0)
    ...:     count=0
    ...:     while is_end_of_world(my_world)==False:
    ...:         sim_step(my_world,p_spread,p_cure)
    ...:         count+=1
    ...:         return count
```

and I keep getting 1 as my out

if I move the return count out an indent like so

```
def time_to_end_of_world(p_spread,p_cure):
    ...:     my_world=set_up_cities()
    ...:     zombify(my_world,0)
    ...:     count=0
    ...:     while is_end_of_world(my_world)==False:
    ...:         sim_step(my_world,p_spread,p_cure)
    ...:         count+=1
    ...:     return count
```

the program crashes...

any ideas?

Comment: The first version of the code is clearly wrong, as it was returning after the first pass of the while loop every time. Without more info on your `sim_step` I'm not sure what could be causing the crash in the second version. Could you be running out of memory perhaps?

Comment: You need to provide the code for the function that is crashing.  Since your program reached the return statement in the first example, you must have some side-effect in either is_end_of_world() or sim_step() which dooms the next execution.

Answer (score 1):

Very likely that someone will be looking at this from this year so....

I'm doing the same assignment as you, and ran into the same issue - however I found the fix. The issue lies with numpy.random.randint() in sim_step().

The random integer function excludes the integer in parenthesis, so your loop never ends because it never infects City 15; only up to 14 if you used numpy.random.randint(15). Change to (16) and it should be fixed.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you ALWAYS return the first time you enter the loop.

By moving the return statement outside the loop, you wait for `is_end_of_world(my_world)==False` to become False to exit the loop. It probably never does, leading to your program crashing.

Answer (score 0):

The first version runs just one step of the simulation.  The second attempts to run the simulation until the world ends.  So something is going wrong in your `sim_step` or `is_end_or_world` code sometime in the steps after the first one.

Answer (score 0):

the problem must be in the sim_step not actually updating my_world, or is_end_of_world is not ever returning true. the return is supposed to be "not indented" like the second example.  post code for sim step and is_end_of_world

Comment: def is_end_of_world(cities):
    how_many=0
    for city in cities:
        if city[1]==True:
            how_many=+1
        if how_many==len(cities):
            return True
        else:
            return False

Comment: 'def sim_step(cities,p_spread,p_cure):
    for index, city in enumerate(cities):
        if(city[1]==True) and (numpy.random.rand() <p_spread):
            random_choice=numpy.random.randint(0,len(city[2]))
            zombify(cities,city[2][random_choice])
        elif index==0:
            pass
        elif(city[1]==True) and (numpy.random.rand() <p_cure):
            cure(cities,index)'

Comment: ok, so I don't see the code that actually assigns cities[x][1]=True. I assum it's in zombify. so check that.  also maybe the world isn't ending. you need to have another counter in your main loop "maxsteps" and run it for 1000 and then print out the values in cities to see how they are doing